# How to redirect specific url to 404 in htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 404

I want to redirect only one specific URl (ex. mypage.com/1234/page/) to error page 404.
How to achieve it in  htaccess?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) activated, you can do that with the **Redirect** directive:

```
Redirect 404 /1234/page/
```

Redirect expects usually the target as 3rd argument, leaving it brings up the configured ErrorDocument. If a target is added it would result in an internal error.

As can be read in the docs:

> If the status is between 300 and 399, the URL argument must be present, otherwise it must be omitted.

(Thanks @w3d for that note!)

Comment: If you specify a status code other than `3xx` in the `Redirect` directive (ie. `404` in this case) - in which case it's not actually a _redirect_ - then the destination URL (3rd argument) should be omitted. Whatever is specified as the appropriate `ErrorDocument` will then be served instead. Specifying the 3rd arg in this instance will actually result in a 500 internal server error.

Comment: Thanks @w3d for spotting that. Answer updated. I usually use Redirect just for ...redirects and thought it would be a nice oneliner for that task.